# Sum of all primes below $n$ without listing all primes below $n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms, computational-number-theory

Asymptotically there is around $\frac{n}{\ln n}$ primes below a given integer $n$. Thus $\frac{n}{\ln n}$ is a lower bound for the time complexity of any algorithm that at some point finds each prime below $n$.

Some algorithms find the number of primes below $n$ without listing all the primes below $n$. Time complexity around $O(n^{\frac{2}{3}})$ is attainable see https://github.com/kimwalisch/primecount

Is there a way to find the sum of all primes below $n$ without listing them all?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378286/find-the-sum-of-all-primes-smaller-than-a-big-number ?

Comment: https://github.com/kimwalisch/primesum